# How can I connect to the Shopify API via web service using SSIS 2K8?

Tags: ssis, shopify

We are working with Shopify to get a web solution implemented. I am looking into how to get data from Shopify using your web service API. We are going to be using SQL Server Integration Services (SSIS) 2K8R2 to do this. Do you happen to have an example that shows how to connect SSIS to the Shopify API for us to use?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of anyone using SSIS to connect to Shopify, so I don't know what that entails. However, Shopify's API is a standard RESTful interface, so I recommend researching how to talk to such services from SSIS.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know there are no specific examples of this. It is a pretty standard rest API so should be straight forward enough. If you can use c# then there is a library you can use. Other wise all you really need to be ably to do is make http requests.

Answer (score 0):

Making webservice calls through an SSIS was never easy. I am not sure if this changed in 2K8R2. Your best bet is probably to create a web/windows/console application and connect to it. I have used the following .NET shopify wrapper with success:

https://github.com/robconery/ShopifyApi